# Macros in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am required to sync two databases, for example DB1 and DB2 that contain tables with the same names. Can I use a macro such that when data gets updated in DB1 in tables 1,2,3 it automatically gets updated in DB2 as well?

Relatively new to MS Access macros, so a step by step explanation would be helpful!

Comment: have done any research? [how to improve your chances of getting an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both databases have the same tables, you can link the tables in DB2 in DB1 & then you can append data from the tables in DB1 to the linked tables of DB2 using an append query & execute the append query in a form timer event. it wouldn't be automatic but you can control the time.